# Is it possible to use the RTC alarm signal on the tamper pin in order to hold that value in a D flip flop? STM32 (bluepill)

Tags: stm32, flipflop, rtc, stm32cubemx

I've been doing a lot of research concerning Low power modes for the STM32 (Bluepill) and I was wondering if I could power my board through VDD and then, right after going into sleep mode, I would use a switch to only power the board through VBAT to save power. The problem here is that the alarm wake up for the RTC won't be able to wake the board up from Vbat alone, my question is: is there a way to store the rising edge from the RTC tamper pin and use it to switch back from VBAT to VDD?
Note: the reason why I am not simply using an RTC alarm wake up from standby is that the board has a strange 140µA current draw in standby which is quite strange so I'm suspecting that it is due to this MCU chip being a clone of the stm32, I unfortunately do not have the option to buy another one at the moment.

Comment: You mean that you need a level shifter or a latch that also shifts level to enable.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 yes , anything that detects the RTC  Alarm's rising edge

Comment: What does it take to wakeup. Add specs. What does RTC output?

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 That's partially  what I am asking about , unfortunately the pulse duration/amplitude it is not specified in the stm32's datasheet nor in its reference manual, the datasheet for the STM32F103C8T6 does explicity say that the RTC alarm does generate a signal ( not a flag) on the RTC TAMPER pin, as I've said however its amplitude is unknown and no matter how hard I tried i couldn't measure its value using a multimeter ( the RTC alarm does wakeup the device so it must be working), I haven't seen anyone attempt this before so I might be doing something wrong.

Comment: As for what the chip takes to wake up, 3.3V~5V into the external regulator is enough for the board to operate ( core, clocks and registers included ).